# What is the best / easiest way to integrate the Jupyter Notebook editor to a 3rd party website?

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook, tornado, jupyter-lab

My friend and I are working on our pet project, a website for hosting algorithms that test sociological hypotheses and accumulate knowledge on sociology. We envision our site to be similar to Wikipedia with one exception: we want to present all the articles on the site in the form of Jupyter Notebooks. Our site engine is based on Django.

Could you please tell me what is the best / easiest way to add the Jupyter Notebook editor to a 3rd party website?

We understand that Jyputer runs on Tornado, that it is single-user, and we need to write a lot of the server logic. Our current understanding is to use the Jyputer Client to work with IPython, take the UI from Jupyter Lab, and write the server handlers ourselves. Could you please tell me if this is the right approach? What should we keep in mind? Is there an easier way to achieve our goal (for example, base our work on Jupyter Server instead of Jupyter Client)?

We would like to focus on developing our site and keep compatibility with Jupyter as much as possible so that we can update / commit a change to the Jupyter project if it is needed.

I would appreciate any advice!